# Calculating Average Temperature , when there are many temperature producers

Tags: java, middleware

```
// AvgTemp.java
public abstract class  AvgTemp {
public void notifyReceived ( String  eventName, Object arg) {
if (eventName.equals("temperatureMeasurement"))  
             { 
                onNewtemperatureMeasurement((TempStruct) arg); 
             } 
}
public abstract void onNewtemperatureMeasurement(TempStruct tempStruct);
}  

// MyAvgTempImpl. java  

public class MyAvgTempImpl  extends AvgTemp {
@Override
public void onNewtemperatureMeasurement(TempStruct tempstruct) {

    //TODO : Need to write a code of  calculating Average Temperature.

    }
}
```

My question is  ``how to write a code of  calculating average temperature (in MyAvgTempImpl. java) in situation when notification coming from many sensors ( producers of temperature data) ?”.

Comment: Is onNewtemperatureMeasurement being invoked in a single-threaded or multi-threaded environment?

Comment: @Thorn :  you can cosider TempStruct as following:                 structure TempStruct {   double sensedTemperatureValue, Time timeStampOfSensing }

Comment: @SamarthBhargava :you can give assume either single-threaded or mulch-threaded environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that information from many sensors comes from one single thread, you will just sum them all and divide by the number of received samples.

On another hand, if that information from many sensors comes from several threads, then you will have to use:

- thread synchronization (using a lock to protect the sum during additions);

or

- atomic operations (no lock needed since the result is always up-to-date and valid);

or

- make sums for each thread and then make the sum of all sums.

I am not a Java programmer so I can't tell how this is done in Java, but at least you have the general idea behind it.

Comment: @ Thanks Gil.  If you could give example in  pseudocode, No necessary in Java. :)

Comment: Well, the peusdo-code is rather similar in all cases - the only thing that changes is the *implementation* (using language-dependent functions). In C, I ended writing my own asm routines for case #2 (atomic operations) but if you want to keep things simple, use case #3 (each thread makes the sum of all its values, and one thread then makes the sum of all the sums).

Comment: Thanks lot . Let me try with Case#3.

Answer (score 0):

In your class MyAvgTempImpl  , add two fields: int count, double sum

In the method onNewtemperatureMeasurement: do count++ & sum+=sensedTemperatureValue;

Add another method to your class MyAvgTempImpl  :

```
double getAverage() {
 return sum/count;
}
```